# How do you copy any folder to a Docker container - while the Dockerfile is present in that folder?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, linux-containers

Let's say I have a repo on git - `REPO`, which I've linked to Docker Cloud for automated builds. The build requires me to copy the entire `REPO` folder onto the container.

Is there any way such that a Dockerfile present **inside** `REPO` can copy it's contents to the container? I've looked up `ADD` and `COPY`, but they work only if the `Dockerfile` is present in a folder that's one directory outside `REPO`.

`FOLDER
   |-> Dockerfile REPO`  -- works

`FOLDER
    |-> REPO
         |-> Dockerfile`    -- doesn't work

Even wildcards, like the command:
`ADD ./* /root/` didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following dockerfile does what you want if i understand you correctly:

```
FROM alpine

RUN mkdir /test
WORKDIR /test

COPY ./ /test/

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

With the following input in `$dir`, and running docker build from `$dir`:

```
Dockerfile somefile   somefolder
```

`/test/` in the docker image contains:

```
/test # ls
Dockerfile  somefile    somefolder
```

Comment: The `COPY ./* /test/` command ignores folder structure. It just dumps all the files and folder contents into `test`.

Comment: I noticed that, `copy ./` without the `*` however preserves it, at least on my test system (docker version 17.03.1-ce)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to do that. Being `.` the root of your `FOLDER` (as you show). You need:

```
docker build . -f REPO/Dockerfile -t imagename
```

And do `COPY` or `ADD` relative to `.`